# DAOFactory передача соедниения

Tags: java, jdbc

Есть абстрактный класс DAOFactory, нужно сделать следующее: при создании DAO отдать ему соединение, чтобы DAO внутри мог использовать его, чтобы не дергать каждый раз DAOFactory, как это сейчас у меня реализовано, DAOFactory daofactory = new DAOFactory(); естественно этого поля здесь быть не должно, на примере кода как это всё реализовать?

```
public abstract class DAOFactory implements DAOFactotyInterface {

    Connection connection = null;

    public Connection getConnection() throws DAOException {
        InputStream read = null;
        try {
            read = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("db.properties");
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.load(read);
            String dbUrl = properties.getProperty("db.url");
            String dbUser = properties.getProperty("db.user");
            String dbPassword = properties.getProperty("db.password");
            String dbDriver = properties.getProperty("db.driver");
            Class.forName(dbDriver);
            if (connection == null) {
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, dbUser, dbPassword);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new DAOException("Properties file is missing ", e);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new DAOException("Driver missing ", e);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new DAOException("No connection ", e);
        } finally {
            if (read != null) {
                try {
                    read.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new DAOException("InputStream is not closed.", e);
                }
            }
        }
        return connection;
    }

    @Override
    public ProfileDAO getProfileDAO() {
        return new MySQLProfileDAO();
    }

    @Override
    public ImagesDAO getImagesDAO() {
        return new MySQLImagesDAO();
    }

    @Override
    public RelationshipsDAO getRelationshipsDAO() {
        return new MySQLRelationshipsDAO();
    }

    @Override
    public ScrobblesDAO getScrobblesDAO() {
        return new MySQLScrobblesDAO();
    }
}


public class MySQLImagesDAO implements ImagesDAO {

    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    Connection connection = null;
    DAOFactory daofactory = new DAOFactory();

    private void getPreparedStatement(String sql) throws DAOException {
        connection = daofactory.getConnection();
        if (preparedStatement == null) {
            try {
                preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new DAOException("Get preparedStatment failed.", e);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @see ImagesDAO#selectAllImages()
     */
    public List<Images> selectAllImages() throws DAOException {
        List<Images> allImages = new ArrayList<>();
        Statement st = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            connection = daofactory.getConnection();
            st = connection.createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery(PrepStatName.SELECT_IMAGES);
            while (rs.next()) {
                Images image = new Images();
                image.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
                image.setIdProfile(rs.getInt("id_profiles"));
                image.setAvatar(rs.getString("avatar"));
                allImages.add(image);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new DAOException("List of images is not selected.", e);
        } finally {
            try {
                if (st != null) {
                    st.close();
                }
                if (rs != null) {
                    rs.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new DAOException("The ResultSet/Statement is not closed.", e);
            }
        }
        return allImages;
    }

    /**
     * @see ImagesDAO#updateImages(Images)
     */
    public void updateImages(Images images) throws DAOException {
        try {
            getPreparedStatement(PrepStatName.UPDATE_IMAGES);
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, images.getIdProfile());
            preparedStatement.setString(2, images.getAvatar());
            preparedStatement.setInt(3, images.getId());
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new DAOException("The images is not updated.", e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @see ImagesDAO#deleteImages(Images)
     */
    public void deleteImages(Images images) throws DAOException {
        try {
            getPreparedStatement(PrepStatName.DEL_IMAGES);
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, images.getId());
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new DAOException("The images is not delete.", e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @see ImagesDAO#insertImages(Images)
     */
    public void insertImages(Images images) throws DAOException {
        try {
            getPreparedStatement(PrepStatName.INSERT_IMAGES);
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, images.getIdProfile());
            preparedStatement.setString(2, images.getAvatar());
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new DAOException("The images is not create.", e);
        }
    }

    public void close() throws DAOException {
        try {
            if (preparedStatement != null) {
                preparedStatement.close();
                preparedStatement = null;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new DAOException("The preparedStatement is not closed. ", e);
        }
        try {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
                connection = null;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new DAOException("The connection is not closed.", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Кода прямо-таки много. Можно ли из этого выделить часть кода, которая непосредственно иллюстрирует вопрос или воспроизводит проблему?

Comment: да, можно меньше, вопрос такой, как из этого метода 
`@Override
    public ImagesDAO getImagesDAO() {
        return new MySQLImagesDAO();
    }` 
передать соединение для DAO, чтобы принять его в методе
`private void getPreparedStatement(String sql) throws DAOException {
    }`
т.е. задание такое: "при создании дао отдать ему соединение, чтобы дао внутри мог использовать его, а не дергать каждый раз фактори"

не уверен что именно в этим местах кода это реализуется, поэтому и выложил полный листинг классов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То. что вы называете фабрикой на самом деле не фабрика, а что-то совсем непонятное.

Давайте вынесем весь код связанный с подключением к базе данных в отдельный класс. По хорошему, здесь лучше использовать готовую имплементацию [`DataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html) из какой-нибудь библиотеки.

```
public class CustomDataSource {

    private final Properties props = new Properties();
    private Connection connection;

    public CustomDataSource(String filename) {
        try ( InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(filename) ) {
            props.load(is);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Properties file is missing", e);
        }
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        if ( connection == null ) {
            try {
                Class.forName(props.getProperty("db.driver"));
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(props.getProperty("db.url"), props.getProperty("db.user"),
                                props.getProperty("db.password"));
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                throw new DAOException("Driver missing", e);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                throw new DAOException("No connection", e);
            }
        }
        return connection;
    }
}
```

Это просто дополнительный класс от которого будут наследоваться все DAO, как признак того, что они работают с JDBC. В него же стоит записывать какие-нибудь дополнительные методы для работы с БД.

```
public abstract class JDBCSupport {

    protected CustomDataSource dataSource = null;

    public JDBCSupport(CustomDataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }
}
```

Идея `checked exceptions` давно умерла, никому уже не хочется тащить `throws` через все классы - пользуйтесь `unchecked`.

```
public class DAOException extends RuntimeException {

    public DAOException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }
}
```

Реализация DAO. То, что вы закрываете все стейтменты это хорошо, но огромные блоки finally не добавляют читаемости. Пользуйтесь конструкцией [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

```
public interface ImagesDao {
    List<Image> findAll();
}

public class MySQLImagesDAO extends JDBCSupport implements ImagesDao {

    public MySQLImagesDAO(CustomDataSource dataSource) {
        super(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Image> findAll() {
        List<Image> images = new ArrayList<>();
        try ( Statement st = dataSource.getConnection().createStatement() ) {
            try ( ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT FROM ..") ) {
                while ( rs.next() ) {
                    Image image = new Image();
                    // set values
                    images.add(image);
                }
                return images;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new DAOException("List of images is not selected.", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Фабрика, если она еще нужна.

```
public class DaoFactory {

    public static MySQLImagesDAO createImagesDao(CustomDataSource dataSource) {
        return new MySQLImagesDAO(dataSource);
    }
}
```

Пример использования:

```
CustomDataSource dataSource = new CustomDataSource("some_config.properties");
MySQLImagesDAO imagesDao = DaoFactory.createImagesDao(dataSource);
List<Image> images = imagesDao.findAll();
```

Comment: Спасибо за столь расширенный ответ, очень полезно и информативно